# Elasticsearch / Kibana Queries

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How to search percentage in Kibana / ES. I have URLs that have %7e and I would like to query those. However, it always shows "No Results Found". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with a `not_analyzed` field?

Try a mapping like this:

```
{
  "template": "*",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [{
        "string_fields": {
          "match": "*",
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can query a field with the name `[fieldname].raw`. Maybe that helps.